# Dynamic Overlays at the Top and Bottom of the Browser Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to figure out how to use JavaScript and jQuery to dynamically create two `<div>` elements and overlay one at the top of the browser window and another at the bottom, with the width of both equal to the width of the browser window.

I'm not really sure how to approach this so I thought I'd just ask the two main questions I have:

1. Is there a way to get the dimensions of the browser window and use that to position the overlays?
2. When creating a statically positioned element, how do you insert them into the DOM such that it does not alter any other part of the page?

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [jQuery width](http://api.jquery.com/width/) / [jQuery height](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

   var $win = $(window),
       $width = $win.width(),
       $height = $win.height();
2. [jQuery append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

   $(body).append(div); <- div is created as a string in a variable

The second assumed they are position:absolute. Wherever you want to append the item, just choose the parent you want and apply as needed.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Unfortunately, `position` appears to only give me the top and left coordinates. It doesn't give me the width or height.

Comment: well then expand on it! var $win = $(window), $pos = $win.position(), $top = $pos.top, $width = $win.width(), $height = $win.height();

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't follow what I just said, which was that `position()` does give me the width or height. According to http://api.jquery.com/position/, "Returns an object containing the properties top and left." But I found I can use `$(window).width()` and `$(window).height()`.

Comment: in your original statement, you did refer to getting the dimensions of the browser window, but also positioning the overlays relative to that window. i must have misunderstood, i thought you were looking for both. regardless, the example i gave in my previous comment gave that; if you're using $(window) twice, capture it in a variable, and request the width/height of that variable. i edited my original answer to reflect.